# Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I applied the below code in my tableview's `viewforHeaderInSection` method. I get error in line when I check `dictkey >= 3`:

> Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type  'Any' and 'Int'

```
else if finalDict.count > 0 {
        print(section)
        let dictKey =  selectedValueArray[section]
        print(dictKey)
        if self.finalDict.object(forKey: String(describing: dictKey)) != nil {          
           let diaryRowArray = self.finalDict.object(forKey:  String(describing: dictKey)) as! NSArray
           print(diaryRowArray.count)
           print(diaryRowArray)
                if dictKey >= 3 
                   var tempsection = section
                   tempsection = 0
                   let diarydescription = diaryRowArray[tempsection] as! DiaryModel
                   headerLabel.text = diarydescription.diary_category_name
                   print(headerLabel.text!)
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: Are you still having a problem or is it sorted?

Comment: No , problem is solved.  Thanks

Comment: Okay you should mark an answer as right if one of them solved it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know its defiantly going to be a Int (which it should be if its a table row) can't you force case it to an Int

```
let dictKey = selectedValueArray[section] as! Int
if(dictKey >= 3) {
    print("It's equal to or greater than 3")
}
```

If it could be another type(i.e String) you can cast it to an Int then check if its nil

```
let dictKey = selectedValueArray[section] as? Int

if(dictKey != nil) {
    if(dictKey! >= 3) {
        print("It's equal to or greater than 3")
    }
}
```

Or a third option could be to use an if let statement

```
if let dictKey = selectedValueArray[section] as? Int {
    //check if its greater than 3
    if(dictKey >= 3) {
        print("It's equal to or greater than 3")
    }
}
```

Edit: 
If your array is an array of strings as numbers (i.e ["1", "2", "3" ,"4"]) try this

```
let dictKey = Int(selectedValueArray[section])
```

If your array is an array of type any then you will ned to cast it as a string array then cast the value to an int.

```
let stringArray = selectedValueArray as! [String]
let dictKey = Int(stringArray[section])
```

Comment: "not working" let dictKey = selectedValueArray[section] as! Int

Comment: What does it say the problem is with that line?

Comment: " let dictKey =  selectedValueArray[section] as! Int " when i execute it show me error like " Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x1130b10e8) to 'NSNumber' (0x110322488). "                                i want to check as : if dictkey > 3  {                             var tempsection = section
                            tempsection = 0
                            let diarydescription = diaryRowArray[tempsection] as! DiaryModel
                            headerLabel.text = diarydescription.diary_category_name
                            print(headerLabel.text!)
}

Comment: Okay that error is saying that its a string which can't cast to an Int. So does that me that the selectedValueArray is an array that has string values?

Comment: yes selectedValueArrayhas string value. so  now what  i have to do ?

Comment: "your  answer working thanks  but i apply code that mention below"  let temp = String(describing: dictKey)
                        print(temp)
                        let tempdict = Int(temp)
                        if tempdict! >= 3 {
                            var tempsection = section
                            tempsection = 0
                            let diarydescription = diaryRowArray[tempsection] as! DiaryModel
                            headerLabel.text = diarydescription.diary_category_name
                            print(headerLabel.text!)
                        }

Comment: Okay good. Yes i changed my answer as i didn't know it was an array of strings. If my answer is working for you please mark is as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare between `dictKey >= 3` since 3 is integer and dictKey is Any. You have to type cast `dictkey` as :

```
guard let dictKey = selectedValueArray[section] as? Int else {return}
```

Then you can compare it.

Comment: after added your suggested line how can i check dictkey is greater than 3 ?

Comment: cast? why not describe `selectedValueArray` as `var selectedValueArray: [Int]`

Comment: Now you can check how you are doing now 'if dictKey >= 3' since both are Int now.

Comment: selectedValueArray is my mutablerray, where i store selected value from tableview. and in table header method i check value of selecteValueArray one by one using dictKey like " let dictKey =  selectedValueArray[section] " now i want to check dictkey is greater than 3 or not as i mention code in question so that i print section header

Comment: So just apply condition whenever you want to test it.

Comment: "not working"                    let dictKey =  selectedValueArray[section] as! Int